# MRTK Photon Unity Networking 'AnchorModuleScript' namespace not found

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, multi-user

While following the [mrtk tutorial on multi-user capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-sharing-02), there has been one CS0246 error that I haven't been able to avoid.

After importing PUN 2 from the asset store, all CS0246 errors from importing the MultiUserCapibilities package are resolved except for `Assets\MRTK.Tutorials.MultiUserCapabilities\Scripts\SharingModuleScript.cs(7,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AnchorModuleScript' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

I have followed this tutorial with my current project on Unity 2020.3.29f, the same project updated to Unity 2021, and a blank Unity 2020 LTS project following only the essential steps (switching build platform, importing MRTK foundation and OpenXR through the feature tool, and setting up MRTK and OpenXR in Unity). All of them only throw this one error. I also updated my Windows SDK and restarted my PC as many other solutions suggest.

My best guess is that this is something on Microsoft's end.

---

- Windows 10 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1645)
- Windows SDK version 2104 (10.0.20348.0)
- Unity 2020.3.29f1
- MRTK 2.7.3
- OpenXR 1.4.0

Comment: How did you solve this issue ? only with adding one more package from the current solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [this](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityLearning/releases/download/azure-spatial-anchors-v2.5.3.1/MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.XRplugginManagement.2.5.3.unitypackage)  Unity package.

Microsoft assumes you've completed the ['Use Azure Spatial Anchors to anchor objects in the real world'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/azure-spatial-anchors-tutorials/) tutorial (in which you download that package on the third page), which is part of the  ['HoloLens 2 fundamentals'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/beginner-hololens-2-tutorials/) tutorials. It's also stated that having followed those tutorials is part of the prequisites to the multi-user capabilities tutorial: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TsvL.png).

Comment: Installing the missing one I get `The type or namespace name 'Azure'` `The type or namespace name 'SpatialAnchorManager'` and some other missing ones. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and just fixed it.

There are several packages that you need to install before adding the ones listed at mrtk tutorial on multi-user capabilities.

I solved it by installing the Unity packages of all the steps in [HoloLens 2 fundamentals: develop mixed reality applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/paths/beginner-hololens-2-tutorials/), you only need to get to the first 2 steps of each Learning Module and install by order their listed Unity Packages.

In short you need to follow the prerequisites to this tutorial.
At the end your Projects tab should look something like this: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqYZy.png)

Comment: To improve the quality of the answer I would suggest you transfer some distilled information from the links you posted to here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting errors from "using Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors" and Azure not being found on imports. Try installing components from the Azure MixedReality Services tab from the MS Mixed Reality Feature Tool.

Before
[AzureErrors Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kEE7.png)

Imports for solution
[Sucessfully found required imports in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5uaw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same errors and I fixed them. Here is my approach;

1- Choose all Azure packages (except iOS and Android) from the "Mixed Reality Feature Tool" during the MRTK setup.

2- Do all configurations based on this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/learn-mrtk-tutorials/1-1-introduction) and this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-sharing-02)

3- As a last step import unity package called "MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.XRplugginManagement.2.5.3.unitypackage"

That's it. Here is my assets folder look:

[image]